# Lebesgue Measure in relation to product measure

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $X=Y=[0,1]$ and let $\mathscr M$ be the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$. Show that any open subset of $X\times Y$ is $\mathscr M\times \mathscr M$ measurable.

My approach: By the compactness of $X\times Y$ of every open set in $X\times Y$ will be covered by a countable disjoint collection of measurable rectangles whose union is a measurable rectangle. But I do not know what to do from there. Can someone help me out.

Comment: If $ U $ is an open subset of $ [0,1]^{2} $, then it is the union of a countable collection of measurable rectangles (you don’t need disjointness). As each open rectangle in $ [0,1]^{2} $ is by definition in the product $ \sigma $-algebra $ M \otimes M $ on $ [0,1]^{2} $, and as any $ \sigma $-algebra is by definition closed under countable unions, we conclude that $ U $ is $ (M \otimes M) $-measurable.

Comment: @BerrickFillmore... can I say the complement of this collection of measurable rectangles are closed set and therefore it is measurable? Since the complement of a measurable set is measurable by the symmetry definition of measurability. Thus each Borel set in XxY is measurable

Comment: The complement of a measurable rectangle isn’t necessarily closed. However, we can arrange for each measurable rectangle in our collection to be open. In fact, this is what’s usually done because we must tie our argument back to what $ M $ is, namely, a Borel $ \sigma $-algebra on $ [0,1] $.

Comment: @BerrickFillmore... but the requirement for Sigma algebra are

1. It contains the empty set.
2. If A is in the sigma-algebra, then the complement of A is there. 
3. It is closed under countable unions of disjoint sets.

How do I make sure the second condition is satisfied?

Comment: I think that you’re confused by the use of the word ‘closed’ here. Being ‘closed’ under countable unions means that for any countable collection $ \mathcal{C} $ of measurable subsets, $ \bigcup \mathcal{C} $ is measurable. It doesn’t mean that $ \bigcup \mathcal{C} $ is topologically closed.

Comment: That certainly helps. I do appreciate it.

Comment: You’re welcome!